# Pass parameter to user control loaded in a frame XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have several frames that load **same** user control `User_Ctrl_foo.xaml`, however I want to pass a single parameter to  the frame from this **xaml**

```
<StackPanel>
    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Gray" FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
     <Frame Name="form1" Content="Form" Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=chk1,Converter={StaticResource b1v}}" Source="Form/User_Ctrl_foo.xaml" Height="600" Width="410" Margin="0"></Frame>


                                    </Border>
                                </StackPanel>
<StackPanel>
    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Gray" FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
     <Frame Name="form2" Content="Form" Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=chk2,Converter={StaticResource b2v}}" Source="Form/User_Ctrl_foo.xaml" Height="600" Width="410" Margin="0"></Frame>


                                    </Border>
                                </StackPanel>
```

How can I pass a parameter to Frame `"form1"` and other parameter to `"form2"`

Comment: Make your own implementation of `Frame` with additional `Properties` where you can Bind something or pass some parameters.